# CSS alignment issue with float right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [bootstrap toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) in my project, it works really nice, but when I'm trying to align the toggle div to the right the text (on the left) and div are not aligning anymore.

I was reading about this issue and found that the `clearfix` class can help here, and it did solve some of the problems, but it's still not looking like it should.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LiranBo/t7jee7sk/)

```
<ul class="list-group" style="width:200px">
    <li class="list-group-item active">
         <h5 class="list-group-item-heading">
             <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
             Settings
         </h5>

    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
         <h5 class="list-group-item-text clearfix">
             Data source 
             <div class="toggle btn btn-primary" data-toggle="toggle" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;float: right;">
                 <input class="pull-right" type="checkbox" checked="" data-toggle="toggle">
                     <div class="toggle-group">
                         <label class="btn btn-primary toggle-on">On</label>
                         <label class="btn btn-default active toggle-off">Off</label>
                         <span class="toggle-handle btn btn-default"></span>
                     </div>
             </div> 
         </h5>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is how I wish it will look (never mind the icon please):

[image]

Comment: this is an issue with your line-height. Your default lineheight is the pixel ammount of your letter size, since your datatoggle is much bigger than your text lineheight, you need to set that propperly. your text is 14 px, while your datatoggle is 32, so ideal lineheight is 2.3 / 2.4

Comment: may I ask then why is it not an issue when I don't use  float right?

Comment: Don't nest a `div` inside `h5`

Comment: it does work thanks, I wasted so much time on this...
@Manoj Kumar - thanks for the tip, this code is auto-generated for me, so I'll just replace the h5.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an element outside "Data source" and add `line-height: 32px;` for it :

```html
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group" style="width:200px">
    <li class="list-group-item active">
         <h5 class="list-group-item-heading">
             <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
             Settings
         </h5>

    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
         <h5 class="list-group-item-text clearfix">
             <span style="line-height: 32px;">Data source</span> 
             <div class="toggle btn btn-primary" data-toggle="toggle" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;float: right;">
                 <input class="pull-right" type="checkbox" checked="" data-toggle="toggle">
                     <div class="toggle-group">
                         <label class="btn btn-primary toggle-on">On</label>
                         <label class="btn btn-default active toggle-off">Off</label>
                         <span class="toggle-handle btn btn-default"></span>
                     </div>
             </div> 
         </h5>
    </li>
</ul>
```